# strrchr not working as expected

Tags: php

I have series of characters which look like this:

```
10.357669 , 125.106745 , 2015-08-21T05:59:34Z , 64,12,015,000000,0028,0028,0026,PETER,WHITE , 044
10.400749 , 125.119000 , 2015-08-20T04:23:46Z , 64,12,025,000000,0003,0003,0003,CHRISTOPHER,KING , 037
10.400755 , 125.118853 , 2015-08-20T04:30:04Z , 64,12,025,000000,0025,0025,0025,JOHNY,SMITH , 038
```

This is from a csv file, and I need to get the last 3 characters. The names shouldn't be there as they are not needed but as they were uploaded by users (who were told of the format but too hardheaded to follow) I cannot do anything about it but to clean it. Everything else is needed. So I don't have a problem with the other data before the names. I am having difficulty with the data after the names. I just need the last 3 characters after the last occurrence of **","**.

Searching, I came up with **strrchr** which finds the last occurrence of a character in a string, and tried to follow the format, I came up with this code:

```
$data10 =   trim(mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]));        //name_id
$ndata10=  strrchr($data10, ",");
```

But the result was:

```
000
000
000
```

Instead of :

```
044
037
038
```

What did I miss? TIA

Comment: 1) Why do you escape the data? 2) What is the output of: `var_dump($data[10]);` ?

Comment: print_r $data10 what is gives you?

Comment: If it's a csv file, why don't you just read the file, and create a new one without the data which isn't needed?

Comment: @Rizier123, 1) As I have said, the data is not needed. 2)  The output of that is string 'PETER' (length=5) string 'CHRISTOPHER' (length=11)
string 'JOHNY' (length=5)

Comment: @IlanHasanov, print_r gives PETERCHRISTOPHERJOHNY

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `mysql_real_scape_string()` function. I test this code:

```
   <?php
    $str = "10.357669 , 125.106745 , 2015-08-21T05:59:34Z , 64,12,015,000000,0028,0028,0026,PETER,WHITE , 044
    10.400749 , 125.119000 , 2015-08-20T04:23:46Z , 64,12,025,000000,0003,0003,0003,CHRISTOPHER,KING , 037
    10.400755 , 125.118853 , 2015-08-20T04:30:04Z , 64,12,025,000000,0025,0025,0025,JOHNY,SMITH , 038";

    $data10 =   trim($str);        //name_id
    $ndata10=  strrchr($data10, ",");
    echo $ndata10;
    ?>
```

The result is: `, 038`
You can test in http://phpfiddle.org/

Is a good result.

If you need line by line, you must to `explode()` the string in all breaking line, and then `strrchr()` each line.

Good luck

Comment: Actually before posting the question, I have tried removing `mysql_real_scape_string()` and `trim()`, but the result is still 000

Comment: Put the content of `$data[0]` because if it returns `000` it's because this is the real result.

Comment: I now get the idea why I am still getting the `000`. I now need to get the string after the last occurrence of **","** from each line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data stored in a csv file, let's try to parse this file and use the data in the column you need.

Example:

```
<?php

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('sample.csv'));

print_r($csv); // do a print to check the data

foreach ($csv as $row)
    print trim($csv[12]) . PHP_EOL; // let's print the values on the last column
    // we're using trim to do away with the extra spaces and newlines and such
```